# API Platform - GraphQL - how to query for a Calculated Field?

Tags: symfony, graphql, symfony4, api-platform.com, symfony5

We need to use Calculated Fields (the equivalent of JMSSerializer's @VirtualProperty for API Platform) and all is fine and dandy when we interact with the backend the old school way. However, we can't figure out how to query this calculated field on the GraphQL endpoint. For example:

```
/**
     * Undocumented function.
     *
     * @Serializer\VirtualProperty()
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->name.$this->description;
    }
```

Regular query:

```
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/platform/api/properties?page=1" -H "accept: application/ld+json"...
```

Regular result:

```
{
  "@context": "/platform/api/contexts/Property",
  "@id": "/platform/api/properties",
  "@type": "hydra:Collection",
  "hydra:member": [
    {
      "@id": "/platform/api/properties/1",
      "@type": "Property",
      "area": "0.00",
      "bathroomCount": 2,
      "bedroomCount": 2,
      "floorCount": 2,
      "description": "bar",
      "name": "foo",
      "slug": "foobar" // The calculated property
    },...
```

GraphQL query:

```
{
  properties {
    edges {
      node {
        slug
      }
    }
  }
}
```

GraphQL result:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"slug\" on type \"Property\".",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "graphql"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 9
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: other property (f.e. `area`) works? type definition updated - browsable by graphiql/docs ?

Comment: Yes, all the other regular properties (not Calculated Field) work fine. Type definition is not in graphiql/docs, but it is present in re doc.

Comment: try normal ` @var string|null ... protected $slug; ` and `getSlug` without direcitves

Answer (score 0):

It appears this was an issue with caching, specifically redis annotations cache. Make sure you clear all caches, if you have such an issue.